# How to make JIRA accessible to http://jira.example.com?

Tags: apache, jira, httpd.conf

Following the installation instruction, JIRA is now available on :
http://example.com:8080/

However I want it to be accessible on http://jira.example.com.

I followed these instruction : https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/integrating-jira-with-apache-185729645.html

Now http://example:8080/ redirects on http://jira.example.com but nothing gets displayed.

Any ideas on how I could solve it ?

ps : I am restarting the httpd with "`service httpd restart`" after each changes.

Comment: When you say "nothing gets displayed" what is the HTTP result?  Do you get a 500, empty 200 etc.  Can you confirm the response headers indicate the tomcat server is receiving the requests or is apache not correctly handling the passthrough to jira?

Comment: I think it's empty, Chrome says : ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Then you're encountering a DNS error, nothing more.  Check this with external nameservers using something like [google toolbox dig](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/) as well as locally.

Comment: when I perform a ns lookup I get server can't find jira.example.com: NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that jira.example.com cannot be resolved at all.  I suspect you may not have DNS entries in place to resolve to your server.  For local testing you could try a [hosts file override](https://wpengine.com/support/emulate-dns-change-with-the-hosts-file-trick/), but you'll need to modify DNS records in order to resolve this further abroad.

Once resolved in DNS you should have JIRA or Apache errors to further investigate/debug, or if you're lucky you'l have a working JIRA server :)